# Event to observe invoice creation and get the invoiced item quantities

Tags: orders, invoice, quantity

I need to observe the invoice creation event and get only the invoiced item quantities since I use partial invoicing sometimes.

I tried the events `sales_order_invoice_save_after` and `sales_order_invoice_pay` and found that `sales_order_invoice_save_after` is fired every time a change is made to invoice. So i used `sales_order_invoice_pay` and got the items into a log using this code

```
$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
      $name = $item->getName();
      $type = $item->getSku();
      $id = $item->getProductId();
      $qty = $item->getQty();
      Mage::log($name.' '.$type.' '.$id.' '.$qty.' '.$parentId , null, 'test.log', true); 
}
```

Most of my products are configurable products. In the log file I get two lines for the same order, configurable product details and simple product details. Also the `$qty` value for the configurable product shows the invoiced quantity(in case of partial invoice) and the simple product `$qty` shows the ordered quantity.

How do I get only the simple product details with the invoiced qunatity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

James
As you want you works in on  `invoice creation time you can` use `getOrigData('entity_id')`

On creation on  `invoice it always give the null value` and you `can use sales_order_invoice_save_after` events

**so you try use**

```
$invoiceId = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice()->getOrigData('entity_id');
if(is_null($invoiceId )){
// do your logic
}
```

an for getting  item qty try this

```
   foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item){
                if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                /* Draw item */

        $name = $item->getName();
        $type = $item->getSku();
        $id = $item->getProductId();
        $qty = $item->getQty();

        }
```

Comment: @AmithBera thanks. I used the `sales_order_invoice_pay` event itself and used your function to get the item qunatity